# How can I get around Excel's URL Limitation?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I'm using the excellent xlsxwriter to build spreadsheets with Python. I've become aware of [the issue](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/110) where you can only write 40k or so URLS to a sheet before you start getting warned and the functionality is gated.

Is there a way to write the urls as strings in such a way that the Excel application will not interpret the url as a string on open (and therefore allow me
to add unlimited urls)? I get that those URLs won't be clickable, but it's better than nothing in this case for me.

Comment: I take it breaking up the sheet into multiple sheets is not an option?

Comment: It's not preferred. I actually prefer that it be a non-clickable link (as for some reasons the links don't work properly anyway for this particular host). I feel like I should be able to write it as a string (maybe with num_format) so that it's copyable by the Excel user but so that Excel doesn't "know" it's a URL.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Excel's limit is around 65k urls per worksheet. XlsxWriter warns if you exceed that.

> Is there a way to write the urls as strings in such a way that the Excel application will not interpret the url as a string on open (and therefore allow me to add unlimited urls)

XlsxWriter has a [constructor option](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/workbook.html#constructor) to turn off conversion of strings to urls:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename, {'strings_to_urls': False})
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm using it with Pandas, which uses the constructor for me. Is there a way to change the setting after the instance exists (or, since I'm guessing that—as the author—you're familiar with what's going on under the hood with Pandas, I can easily modify that functionality when pandas is creating the instance)?

Comment: You can pass XlsxWriter contractor options via Pandas. Something like this: `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter', options={'strings_to_urls': False})`

Comment: With the newest versions of pandas the syntax has changed to `pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter', engine_kwargs={'options': {'strings_to_urls': False}})`