# EPPlus corrupt Excel file when having more than 65,530 rows

Tags: excel, hyperlink, epplus, corrupt

I'm running into an issue with EPPlus when there are more than 65,530 rows that have a column with a hyperlink. The example below is configured to create 65,530 rows. With this number it will create the Excel file correctly (not corrupt). Once you run it with anything over 65,530, the Excel file will be created but when you open it, Excel will report that is corrupt. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

```
try
{

    int maxRowsToCreate = 65530;  //-- no errors will be generated
    //int maxRowsToCreate = 65531;  //-- error will be generated. The Excel file will be created but will give an error when trying to open it.

    string report = string.Format("D:\\temp\\hypelinkIssue-{0}.xlsx", maxRowsToCreate.ToString());

    if (File.Exists(report))
    {
        File.Delete(report);
    }

    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo(report)))
    {
        //Add the Content sheet
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Catalog");
        ws.View.ShowGridLines = true;

        var namedStyle = pck.Workbook.Styles.CreateNamedStyle("HyperLink");   //This one is language dependent
        namedStyle.Style.Font.UnderLine = true;
        namedStyle.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Blue);

        ws.Column(1).Width = 100;

        int rowIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < maxRowsToCreate; i++)
        {
            rowIndex += 1;

            string fullFilePath = string.Format("D:\\temp\\{0}", Path.GetRandomFileName());

            ws.Cells[rowIndex, 1].StyleName = "HyperLink";
            ws.Cells[rowIndex, 1].Hyperlink = new Uri(string.Format(@"file:///{0}", fullFilePath));
            ws.Cells[rowIndex, 1].Value = fullFilePath;
        }

        pck.Save();
    }

    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(report);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Excel limits the amount of unique URLs in a file to 65,530. You should try to insert them as text, instead of a url.

For a possible solution, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35737844/10346096).

Comment: Wow! I will try to come up with a different approach. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The issue occurs when using ".Hyperlink". If instead I use ".Formula" and populate it with the "=HYPERLINK" Excel formula, it works fine. I was able to create 250k records with unique hyperlink using this approach. I did not try more than 250k but hopefully it will work fine.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

```
/*
This only works with LESS than 65,530 hyperlinks
*/
ws.Cells[rowIndex, 1].StyleName = "HyperLink";
ws.Cells[rowIndex, 1].Hyperlink = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelHyperLink(fullFilePath, ExcelHyperLink.UriSchemeFile);
ws.Cells[rowIndex, 1].Value = fullFilePath;


/*
This works with more that 65,530 hyperlinks
*/
string cellFormula = string.Format("=HYPERLINK(\"{0}\")", filePath);
ws.Cells[rowIndex, 1].Formula = cellFormula;
```